# How to enable foreground notification for only some UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter, swift5

I want to show notification in foreground for only some selected UIViewControllers.

But When I set NotificationCenter to receive notification in foreground for specific UIViewController then Swift do it for global scope. In some screen I don't want to see notification to appear in foreground and for that I have to specify in every screen to show notification in foreground or not which leads to lot of code usually unmanaged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the condition in the notification delegate method to show notification for a specific view controller or not.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    let navigationController: UINavigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

    if (navigationController.topViewController is FirstViewController) || (navigationController.topViewController is SecondViewController) { 

        //Show notification for First and Second ViewController 
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
    else {
       //Do whatever when you don't want to show notification
    }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful to you...

Comment: This is nice way to do for specific UIViewControllers